# Gitlab rule for manual job without blocked status

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops

I have such difficulty- I have gitlab job with manual rule as

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
```

I need that if the job was not started manually, then the pipeline status was not blocked. At the same time, if the job was started, then allow_failure: false

I tried to use allow_failure: true in out of rule, but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain what about this "doesn't work" for you? What's the expected/unexpected behavior? And can you share the entire job definition, including any other rules you have?

Comment: I mean that it doesn't work as I need, pipeline status isn't blocked, but job in failed case has allow failure status.
whole job:
`deploy:app:
  stage: deploy
  extends: [".deployApp"]
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: manual`
By default, in this case allow_failure: false, but if job doesn't run manualy  pipeline status is blocked